# what does avg() mean at grafana alert?

Tags: alert, grafana, grafana-alerts

im confused about avg() at grafana alert, i did not found any document explain the meaning of this.

How does avg() calculate? If I set Evaluate every 5m for 0m, will the avg() same as sum()?
any one can explain how does avg() calculated at this case?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

based on your screenshot you will an alert of get the average of a single metric resulting from query A over the last 192 hours is above `1` and one if it is above `1`.

Please note, that you have only a single alert per panel, this will result in an always-on alert.